# This onBlur is not working the way I want

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

Here I want this onBlur to show another text or input field which is working but whenever i clear the value it should be hiding but right now it is not working the way I want. In easy words whenever I enter content in input field and loose the focus it show sub input field but whenever clear it all it should be hiding but it is not working here is the code

```
   <Typography
                color="#05445E"
                fontFamily="'Jost', sans-serif"
                fontSize={15}
              >
                Email
              </Typography>
              <Input
                fullWidth
                name="email"
                value={user.email}
                onChange={handleChange}
                disableUnderline={true}
                onBlur={handleOTP}
                className={classes.inputEmail}
                endAdornment={
                  <>
                    {user.clearEmail ? (
                      <IconButton
                        onClick={() => clearValue("email", "clearEmail")}
                      >
                        <ClearIcon />
                      </IconButton>
                    ) : (
                      ""
                    )}
                  </>
                }
              />
              {showSecondInput && (
                <>
                  <Typography
                    color="#05445E"
                    fontFamily="'Jost', sans-serif"
                    fontSize={15}
                    sx={{ mt: "15px" }}
                  >
                    Enter OTP
                  </Typography>
                  <Input
                    className={classes.inputEmail}
                    fullWidth
                    type="password"
                  />
                </>
              )}
```

This is the states I have used

```
 const [user, update_user] = useState({
    user_name: "",
    email: "",
    clearUser: false,
    clearEmail: false,
  });
 

  const clearValue = (key, show) => {
    update_user({ ...user, [key]: "", [show]: false });
  };
  const [showSecondInput, setShowSecondInput] = useState(false);

  const handleOTP = (e) => {
    const { name:key } = e.target;

    if(key === "email") setShowSecondInput({ ...showSecondInput, [key]: "", clearEmail: false });
  };

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name: key, value } = event.target;

    if (value) {
      if (key === "user_name")
        update_user({ ...user, [key]: value, clearUser: true });
      else if (key === "email")
        update_user({
          ...user,
          [key]: value,
          clearEmail: true,
        });
    } else
      update_user({
        ...user,
        [key]: "",
        clearUser: false,
        clearEmail: false,
      });
  };
```

The clearValue function is working smoothly without any problem the problem is on blur event..

Comment: You're initial `showSecondInput` value is `false` and in the `handleOTP` function you're setting it to some object and spreading the initial boolean value. Seems like something is going wrong there?

Comment: Yes.. What I want is whenever the input field is empty the sub input field should be hiding

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by checking for the `name` in case you have more `onBlur` with the `handleOTP` function. Then checking if the `value` is a empty string and based on that set the state.

```js
const handleOTP = (e) => {
  const { name, value } = e.target;

  if (name !== "email") return;

  if (value === "") {
    setShowSecondInput(true);
  } else {
    setShowSecondInput(false);
  }
};
```

Comment: No It is not working now whenever I enter data it will now show sub input whenever it goes blur. before it was showing sub input

Comment: So you want the **sub input** to hide when the `email` input has no value? And `onBlur` should to hide / show the **sub input**?

Comment: Yes.. Whenever I enter data in email field and `onBlur` other field show up and if it is empty it should hide I have given there clear button as well which will clear data in input field in Email

Answer (score 0):

I try to use TouchableOpacity onPress instead of onBlur whenever I can.

Simply refactor your code to allow for a single onPress to execute multiple functions at the same time.

example:

```
 <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Signin")}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={clearErrorMessage}>
            <Text style={styles.link}>Already have an account? Sign in instead</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </TouchableOpacity>
```